# "error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds" when flatMap the stream in single line

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a custom class `Custom`.

```
public class Custom {

  private Long id;

  List<Long> ids;

  // getters and setters
}
```

Now I have `List<Custom>` objects. I want to convert `List<Custom>` into `List<Long>`. 
I have written the code as below and it is working fine.

```
    List<Custom> customs = Collections.emptyList();
    Stream<Long> streamL = customs.stream().flatMap(x -> x.getIds().stream());
    List<Long> customIds2 = streamL.collect(Collectors.toList());
    Set<Long> customIds3 = streamL.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Now I'm combining the line2 and line3 into single line as below.

```
    List<Long> customIds = customs.stream().flatMap(x -> x.getIds().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Now, this code is not compiling and I'm getting below error -

```
    error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
            List<Long> customIds = customs.stream().flatMap(x -> x.getIds().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                                                                                            ^
        equality constraints: Set<Long>
        upper bounds: List<Long>,Object
    where R,A,T are type-variables:
        R extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)
        A extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)
        T extends Object declared in interface Stream
```

How can I convert the `List<Custom>` into `Set<Long>` or `List<Long>` correctly

Comment: `Collectors.toSet()`, as its name indicates, creates a Set. Not a List. So you can't assign the result to `List<Long> customIds`.

Comment: The original code would never work, because you can only call `collect()` *once* on `streamL`. The second call throws `IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it as :

```
List<Custom> customs = Collections.emptyList();
Set<Long> customIdSet = customs.stream()
                               .flatMap(x -> x.getIds().stream())
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // toSet and not toList
```

The reason you get a compiler error is that you've used an incorrect `Collector` which returns a List instead of a Set which is your expected return type as you assign it to a variable of `Set<Long>` type.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick :

```
Set<Long> collectSet = customs.stream()
                           .flatMap(x -> x.getIds().stream())
                           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

You are trying to convert a `Set` to a `List` which is not possible.